# Can someone please guide me to theravada buddhist monastery in France or Netherland?

Tags: theravada

Looking for someone who could guide me to Theravada Buddhist monastery in France or Netherland on July

Comment: Is [this](http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/search.php?keyword=&search=Search&country_id=62&province_id=0&tradition%5B%5D=theravada) or [this](http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/search.php?keyword=&search=Search&country_id=70&province_id=0&tradition%5B%5D=theravada) what you were looking for, i.e. is that an answer to this question?

Comment: I just checked the link. Actually i don't have idea which monastery i should go. I will only two days in france and already have full schedule for city tour. I think I just have time night time. Are you from france @ChrisW ?

Answer (score 4):

> I just checked the link. Actually i don't have idea which monastery i should go. I will only two days in france and already have full schedule for city tour. I think I just have time night time. Are you from france @ChrisW

I am in France, but not near Paris. I can read French, if that's any help: if you want me to search for something specific on the internet. Two days with already a full schedule isn't very much time.

---

This page, [Les Centres et les Temples Bouddhistes à Paris (75)](http://www.comprendrebouddhisme.com/centres/temple-france/ile-de-france/paris-75.html) says it lists Buddhist centres and temples in Paris. Almost all of them are either Zen or Tibetan.

This one is Theravada (Thai Forest):

```
18. Association Bouddhique Theravâda "Vivekârâma"
école : Theravâda (tradition des "moines de forêt" de Thaïlande) 

lieu de pratique : 14 rue Philibert Lucot 75013 Paris

siège social : c/o Michel-Henri Dufour 
22 rue de la Grange Aubel 71000 Sancé Tél. 03.85.20.14.42
```

Their web site is at http://vivekarama.fr/activites-3/activites-paris
which says they have 3-hour guided sessions every third Sunday, and free sessions once a month on Fridays (it's not a temple, they meet in a room somewhere).

They have [a calendar here](http://vivekarama.fr/activites-3/activites-paris/activites-paris-infos#contact) and they ask you to contact them (by email I suppose) first.

So that's not a monastery.

---

[This search](http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/search.php?keyword=&search=Search&country_id=62&province_id=761&tradition%5B%5D=theravada) finds no Theravada in Paris.

---

There's a centre that's near Paris: http://centrebouddhique.fr/ It's near the "Le Bourget" airport. They have [a calendar here](http://centrebouddhique.fr/calendrier-2014/).

---

There's a [Pagoda in Vincennes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagode_de_Vincennes) which is virtually inside Paris (Vincennes are a wood or park, on the south east edge of Paris): it's not Theravada and not a monastery but is a multi-denominational Buddhist place (without a teacher) that might be within your reach if you have limited time in Paris.

---

If you're looking for Theravada monasteries, [this map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zc9KxYuVQykc.kfaX9cYKqd5o) says it shows the Theravada monasteries in Europe.

The two which are near Paris have these web sites:

- http://dhammayutta.free.fr/ (located 11 km from Paris, beware that the web site is 2012)
- http://www.burmeseclassic.org/dir.php

  ```
  U Kumara Association Bouddhiste Birmane 
  63 Avenue Maurice Thorez 94200 Ivry sur seine France.
  Tel: 33 (0) 146717240, 33 (0) 677463943
  ```

---

In summary I don't know whether you'll be able to go to a Theravada Buddhist monastery in France.

---

If you have questions about travel rather than Buddhism there's a [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) site which may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ChrisW.i had  checked all links you gave me.  Hopefully still have free time for me to go one of those monastery .

Answer (score 2):

If you go to [this website](http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/search.php?keyword=&search=Search&country_id=70&province_id=0&tradition%5B%5D=theravada) you will see a list of theravada monasteries in The Netherlands.

If you press one of them there is more information such as *email, website* and also *google maps* to easier find their location.

Comment: Very thank you lanka

Comment: Your welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned elsewhere that you like Thich Nhat Hanh, you may want to visit his monastery, Plum Village, in Bordeauax, France - http://plumvillage.org

It is a beautiful monastery with very mature practitioners both lay and ordained.

Thich Nhat Hanh is Vietnamese Zen, not Theravada but a great practitioner and in my opinion a living Bodhisattva.

Edit: You say you only have 2 days. I don't know where in France you will be, but it is a big country, and getting to Bordeaux from Paris will take a 1-2 hour flight, and a bus or car from there to the monastery - about 100kms.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. Thich nhat hanh is a living Bodhisattva. I always feel calm while listening his speech even still i can watch from youtube;) It's quite far to get that monastery I thought. Hopefully I still have free time to get there. Are you from France  @Buddho?

Comment: @sherly I used to live nearby, but no longer. If you can manage the time please consider a retreat there, it is life changing.

Comment: Sure. I also want to do retreat  if possible @buddho

Comment: @sherly excellent, may you get the time and opportunity.

Comment: Yes, If I lived in France or able to get a France visa I would definitely visit Plum Village and maybe become a monk there. That's a wonderful place but they take too much money even from the monk candidates

Answer (score 0):

Paris International Buddhist Center ( paris vihara ) is one of the oldest and well-established Buddhist Temples in Europe.